# Redirect http://www.saledresses.net/index.php?p=home to http://www.saledresses.net/

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, pinnacle-cart

I'm using a pinnacle cart shopping cart.  I've been able to redirect index.php but have not been able to redirect http://www.saledresses.net/index.php?p=home to http://www.saledresses.net/.  I feel this would be important because this is the url that is linked to with the home button on every page of the site.

Thank You,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=home$ [NC]
RewriteRule - http://www.salesdress.net/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In admin side there is a option to add your home page URL - I guess it is in home page settings or SEO settings